# Centering text + buttons on page not working

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a page where you can click on a button and it will redirect you to a certain page. I got pretty far. and its my first time doing something like this. My problem is that im not getting it to center properpy when the screen is getting bigger after a certain amount. (my problem: http://prntscr.com/k82ogb )
https://jsfiddle.net/tkeuper/pednvrf3

```
        <div class="header-content">
      <h1>Server</h1>
      <p></p>
      <a class="btn" href=:"#">Forum</a>
      <a class="btn" href=:"#">Store</a>
      <a class="btn" href=:"#">Bedwars Stats</a>
      <a class="btn" href=:"#">Punishments</a>
    </div>
```

But im not sure. i used a youtube video to make the page: https://youtube.com/watch?v=Xy3GlrddZFI

Its my first time so i dont know a lot. xD

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Just add `margin: auto;` on your `header-content` to center it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `margin: 0 auto;` to the `.header-content`

This will force the margin on either side of your container to fill the remaining space equally, resulting in a centered element.

I modified your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pednvrf3/3/

Comment: Thanks, and do you know how i send poeple to a different page because it doesnt work the way i want it to. It puts the link behind the page im already on instead of replacing it.  http://prntscr.com/k8307o

Comment: Your anchor tags should have hrefs that point to the different files of your site. For example: `<a href="forum.html">Forum</a>` might point to your forum page. It depends on what you call your files and where they are. Here's a bit more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, i have done it by using google and javascript Thanks tho.